# JavaScript deprecation warnings?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, firefox, eslint, chromium

In eslint(v7.19.0)/eclipse(2020-12[4.18.0])/chromium(90.0.4416.0)/firefox(85.0)/etc Is there a way to warn when a deprecated native function is used?

For example using the deprecated form of [RTCPeerConnection.createOffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer) fails to produce a warning in the above mentioned tools.

@howlger said that's deprecated parameters and maybe that's technically true in JavaScript (unlike Java which cares about function signatures) so another example is [window.forward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/forward) which eslint/eclipse fail to pick up on but browsers say "is not a function" because it's been deprecated and removed.

Maybe that's also "unclear" so [Date.getYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) is a 3rd example which works in browsers, produces no warnings and is deprecated.

Granted JavaScript is fluid and a project may implement a function anywhere named almost anything but linters should highlight that sort of bad practice encouraging coders to use function names that have not been built-in deprecated at any point.

Here is a minimal reproducible test;

```
# eslint test.js 
# eslint --env-info
Environment Info:

Node version: v10.19.0
npm version: v7.5.3
Local ESLint version: v7.19.0 (Currently used)
Global ESLint version: Not found
# cat test.js 
/**
 * @deprecated test
 */
function b() {
    new Date().getYear();
}
function a() {
    b();
    window.forward();
}
```

Comment: That's one of the things what ESLint is for, so if it's not flagging things you know are deprecated, you probably want to head on over to https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues first and ask whether that's a bug or just the linter not having been updated for that particular case.

Comment: In the current Eclipse, you will get a warning when using a deprecated JavaScript function or class: https://youtu.be/CNasSgaeIwo?t=693

Comment: There are two kinds of JavaScript supports in Eclipse. Opened with the JavaScript Editor you get JavaScript support by WTP JSDT (also the preferences you mentioned are refering to this) and opened with the Generic Text Editor you get JavaScript support by Wild Web Developer (which uses the VS Code language server). I was referring to the latter.

Comment: Sure, as you can see in my video that I mentioned in my first comment. Maybe you just missed to update Wild Web Developer (which version do you have?) since this is a new feature of the end of last year.

Comment: Did you test what is shown in the video? Because your question is about _"a deprecated function"_, but as an "example" it refers to a function that is not deprecated (only some parameters are deprecated). Please improve your question by providing [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In the current Eclipse in your `test.js` example a warning/info is shown in line 8 telling `b();` is deprecated (same as in my video). Technically, this is not shown by ESLint (as far as I know ESLint can't do this), but by the JavaScript/TypeScript tooling: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#deprecated-support

Comment: My comments are related to what you originally asked. These are not _built-in_ functions. It seems you are talking about functions of the Web APIs (at least you mention only functions of the Web APIs). [Web APIs are typically used with JavaScript, although this doesn't always have to be the case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) (think of executing the code with Node.js, in an Ant script, by Java Nashorn, etc.). [All ESLint core rules are listed here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/).

Comment: I have a similar question: How to find out what in my HTML/CSS/JavaScript code is not supported by a given list of web browsers. Unfortunately, I haven't found yet a better solution than testing and looking at [_Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/) for this yet.